# How to make a condition for multiple list that will show only the array with the same value

Tags: java, android, list, android-studio, arraylist

I want to make a condition in my multiple arrays to get the arraylist with containing "delivered" only. Is there someone who can help me with this?

I already tried the "myOrderItemModelList.contains("Delivered")" But I always get blank results.

```
    List<MyOrderItemModel> myOrderItemModelList = new ArrayList<>();

    myOrderItemModelList.add(new MyOrderItemModel(R.drawable.tide_prod, 2, "Tide Detergent", "149.50", "Ren's Grocery", "Juan Dela cruz", "Order_Received", 4, 3));
    myOrderItemModelList.add(new MyOrderItemModel(R.drawable.tide_prod, 2, "Tide Detergent", "149.75", "Ren's Grocery", "Juan Dela cruz", "On_Process", 0, 5));
    myOrderItemModelList.add(new MyOrderItemModel(R.drawable.tide_prod, 3, "Tide Detergent", "50", "Ren's Grocery", "Juan Dela cruz", "Order_Processed", 1, 0));
    myOrderItemModelList.add(new MyOrderItemModel(R.drawable.tide_prod, 1, "Tide Detergent", "70", "Ren's Grocery", "Juan Dela cruz", "On_Delivery", 1, 1));
    myOrderItemModelList.add(new MyOrderItemModel(R.drawable.tide_prod, 5, "Tide Detergent", "30", "Ren's Grocery", "Juan Dela cruz", "Delivered", 3, 2));
    myOrderItemModelList.add(new MyOrderItemModel(R.drawable.tide_prod, 6, "Tide Detergent", "56", "Ren's Grocery", "Juan Dela cruz", "Delivered", 2, 4));
    myOrderItemModelList.add(new MyOrderItemModel(R.drawable.tide_prod, 1, "Tide Detergent", "75", "Ren's Grocery", "Juan Dela cruz", "Cancelled", 5, 2));

    if (myOrderItemModelList.contains("Delivered")) {
        MyOrderItemOnProcessAdapter myOrderItemOnProcessAdapter = new MyOrderItemOnProcessAdapter(myOrderItemModelList);
        my_orders_recyclerview.setAdapter(myOrderItemOnProcessAdapter);
        myOrderItemOnProcessAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: Generate the `equals` method in the MyOrderItemModel model class and it will fix your issue.

Comment: Seems the MyOrderItemModel is a java bean object ? If so, Jaymin's right, you should implement an equals method in your bean .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

myOrderItemModelList.contains("Delivered") will not give you what you want because your list contains MyOrderItemModel instances, not strings.

If you are looking for a filtered list containing only items with status "Delivered", that would be something like this, assuming a status() method on MyOrderItemModel:

```
List<MyOrderItemModel> delivered = myOrderItemModelList.stream().filter( 
  item -> "Delivered".equals(item.status())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or, if you want to do something with the entire list, but only if at least one item has the "Delivered" status:

```
if (myOrderItemModelList.stream().anyMatch(item -> "Delivered".equals(item.status()))) {
      MyOrderItemOnProcessAdapter myOrderItemOnProcessAdapter = new 
      MyOrderItemOnProcessAdapter(myOrderItemModelList);
      my_orders_recyclerview.setAdapter(myOrderItemOnProcessAdapter);
      myOrderItemOnProcessAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<MyOrderItemModel> myDeliveredItemModelList = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0;i<myOrderItemModelList.size();i++){
    MyOrderItemModel myOrderItemModel=myOrderItemModelList.get(i);
    if(myOrderItemModel.getStatus().equals(“Delivered”){
        myDeliveredItemModelList.add(myOrderItemModel);
    }

}
```

From above code you will get new ArrayList myDeliveredItemModelList which containing "delivered".

**Note** :myOrderItemModel.getStatus() —>getStatus replace with your variable

**You final code here:**

```
 List<MyOrderItemModel> myOrderItemModelList = new ArrayList<>();
    myOrderItemModelList.add(new MyOrderItemModel(R.drawable.tide_prod, 2, "Tide Detergent", "149.50", "Ren's Grocery", "Juan Dela cruz", "Order_Received", 4, 3));
    myOrderItemModelList.add(new MyOrderItemModel(R.drawable.tide_prod, 2, "Tide Detergent", "149.75", "Ren's Grocery", "Juan Dela cruz", "On_Process", 0, 5));
    myOrderItemModelList.add(new MyOrderItemModel(R.drawable.tide_prod, 3, "Tide Detergent", "50", "Ren's Grocery", "Juan Dela cruz", "Order_Processed", 1, 0));
    myOrderItemModelList.add(new MyOrderItemModel(R.drawable.tide_prod, 1, "Tide Detergent", "70", "Ren's Grocery", "Juan Dela cruz", "On_Delivery", 1, 1));
    myOrderItemModelList.add(new MyOrderItemModel(R.drawable.tide_prod, 5, "Tide Detergent", "30", "Ren's Grocery", "Juan Dela cruz", "Delivered", 3, 2));
    myOrderItemModelList.add(new MyOrderItemModel(R.drawable.tide_prod, 6, "Tide Detergent", "56", "Ren's Grocery", "Juan Dela cruz", "Delivered", 2, 4));
    myOrderItemModelList.add(new MyOrderItemModel(R.drawable.tide_prod, 1, "Tide Detergent", "75", "Ren's Grocery", "Juan Dela cruz", "Cancelled", 5, 2));



List<MyOrderItemModel> myDeliveredItemModelList = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0;i<myOrderItemModelList.size();i++){
    MyOrderItemModel myOrderItemModel=myOrderItemModelList.get(i);
    if(myOrderItemModel.getStatus().equals(“Delivered”){
        myDeliveredItemModelList.add(myOrderItemModel);
    }

}

  MyOrderItemOnProcessAdapter myOrderItemOnProcessAdapter = new MyOrderItemOnProcessAdapter(myDeliveredItemModelList);
     my_orders_recyclerview.setAdapter(myOrderItemOnProcessAdapter);
     myOrderItemOnProcessAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the status of orders i.e "Delivered" item in the list first and then set the list to the adapter.

You can do it in the following way

```
   List<MyOrderItemModel> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < myOrderItemModelList.size(); i++) {
        MyOrderItemModel myOrderItemModel = myOrderItemModelList.get(i);
        if (myOrderItemModel.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("Delivered")) {
            filteredList.add(myOrderItemModel);
        }

    }
```

Now add `filteredList` to the adapter.

Note : replace `getStatus()` with your getter of status of your `MyOrderItemModel` class

Hope this works!

Answer (score 0):

The contains method of list checks whether exact same object exists or not by looking at the object's equals method. 
So if(myOrderItemModelList.contains(myOrderItemModel)) is the proper way of handling the code. 
And in myOrderItemModel you can override equals method and write something like

`public boolean equals(Object obj)
{ 
    if(obj instanceof MyOrderItemModel)
    {
        MyOrderItemModel m = (MyOrderItemModel)obj;
        return m.delivered.equals(this.delivered);
    }
    return false;
}`

More proper approach would be to iterate the list and check for delivered status.

`public boolean isDelivered(List<MyOrderItemModel > myOrderItemModelList) 
    {

    for(MyOrderItemModel m : myOrderItemModelList)
    {
        if(m.getDelivery.equals("delivered"))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}`

In java 8, you can use something like this.

`myOrderItemModelList.stream().filter(m -> m.getDelivered.equals('Delivered')).count() > 0;`